# Extract information from org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage

Tags: java, soap, cxf

Is there a way to get the soap action from an instance of `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage` ?

I am writing an Interceptor which will log the incoming and outgoing messages to/from my CXF service, and as part of this it would be useful to include the specific soap action being requested.  I've been able to extact useful information from the Soap header using `message.getHeader(name)` and just need the Soap action to complete the log.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure where the soap action is stored, but I have been able to extract information about the request using something similar to this:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>
{
   //...//
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault
    {
       Message inMessage = message.getExchange().getInMessage();
       MessageInfo mi = (MessageInfo) inMessage.get("org.apache.cxf.service.model.MessageInfo");
       String methodName = mi.getOperation().getInputName();
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great - thanks @jt.  It seems this interceptor needs to be added on or after `Phase.PRE_LOGICAL` to ensure that the MessageInfo reference is set.